# Execute Code first Migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I have installed Windows 8.1 pro and moved all MVC projects to new work-space using VS 2013 Community Edition. All projects were using code first migration.
Database Publishing was also done using code first migration. All was running fine before I updated my machine.

But Now when I publish web application to remote servers, 'Publish Web' dialog box not showing "Execute Code first Migration", Instead its showing "Update database" for updating database.
And when I close it, It modifies the publish files for DB First. It seems that some global setting enforcing it to the following code:

```
 <Objects xmlns="">
        <ObjectGroup Name="DefaultConnection" Order="1" Enabled="False">
          <Destination Path="" />
          <Object Type="DbDacFx">
            <PreSource Path="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MVC-20140923125211.mdf;Initial Catalog=MVC-20140923125211;Integrated Security=True" includeData="False" />
            <Source Path="$(IntermediateOutputPath)AutoScripts\DefaultConnection_IncrementalSchemaOnly.dacpac" dacpacAction="Deploy" />
          </Object>
          <UpdateFrom Type="Web.Config">
            <Source MatchValue="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MVC-20140923125211.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVC-20140923125211;Integrated Security=True" MatchAttributes="$(UpdateFromConnectionStringAttributes)" />
          </UpdateFrom>
        </ObjectGroup>
      </Objects>
```

Its strange why "Execute Code first Migration" is not shown for all my projects.

This behavior is same for all my other projects too.

The App_Data databases also not opening. So I changed connectionString' datasource from **Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0** to **Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB (MSSQL Sever 2014 express)**. Changing DataSource worked for opening database though.

I tried the solutions:

- Tried this : ["Execute Code First Migrations" checkbox disappeared from my publish profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664459/execute-code-first-migrations-checkbox-disappeared-from-my-publish-profile)
- Enable Migration -Force
- Clean, Rebuild and restart project and
  Visual Studio.
- Delete and re-import publish file

I tried solutions above few months back. That time the points above worked but now nothing works.

Is there any solution available for this? I wasted my whole day and still not found solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution for this. Manually replacing all ConnectionString name (Defaultconnection) to context name "ApplicationDbContext" without namespaces solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Visual Studio update 4. Go to Extensions and updates under tools.

Comment: VS 2013 Community Edition already comes with update 4. I checked it though. Its showing already with update 4.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful:

[Entity Framework Code First Data Migrations not working with VS2012 Web Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514521/entity-framework-code-first-data-migrations-not-working-with-vs2012-web-deploy)

I myself am still trying to find a simple way to deal with migrations.